# My ubuntu system randomly freezes for about 2-10 seconds

Tags: gnome

I recently did a switch from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have been using it for approximately 6 months. Everything was fine until I watched [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrI5c9PXS5k) and decided to install some of the programs highlighted there. Now my system randomly freezes for around 2-10 seconds. During this period, I can move the mouse and, if I click on something, it takes effect after the freeze is over. I have tried to look for similar questions on the issue but so far nothing has worked.

I checked my logs and every time this error comes up whenever the freeze occurs.

```
JS ERROR: TypeError: this._workspacesViews[i] is undefined
_syncWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:762:13
setWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:752:14
setWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/viewSelector.js:301:33
_updateWorkspacesGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:498:27
vfunc_allocate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:402:14
_computeWindowCenter@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:302:35
_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:160:14
_addWindowClone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1856:21
_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1174:22
_updateWorkspaces@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:232:29
_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:91:14
_updateWorkspacesViews@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:686:24
show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:613:14
show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/viewSelector.js:276:33
_animateVisible@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:580:27
show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:566:14
_onShowAppsButtonToggled@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:1941:31
```

I also tried to look for the error in relation to gnome-shell but so far I have come up empty. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: install some of the programs What programs are we supposed to guess?

Comment: if you have installed some kind of gnome shell extensions for workspaces or additional extensions for dock, disable that and see if the issue still persists, otherwise like suggested above try to give us more information about the extensions installed

Comment: Same issue after installing Ubuntu 20.04.2.0. Most apps freeze from time to time for 1-10 seconds

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your responses. @David I installed the following programs based on the YouTube video highlighted in the question, synaptic, timeshift, preload, tlp and tlp-rdw, numix theme in addition to gnome-tweaks and bleachbit. I thought the project was with numix-themes so I unistalled it but the problem still persisted.

Comment: With so many things to uninstall or try to disable I would make a fresh install. If you think you need all of therm add them one at a time and use the system for a day or 2 between each.